# Reducing convex QCQP to SDP or something better

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, qcqp

I am trying to solve the following QCQP

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x}{\text{minimize}} & x^T P_0 x + q_0^Tx + r_0\\ \text{subject to} & x^T P_1 x + r_1< 0\end{array}$$

where symmetric matrices $P_0, P_1$ are positive semi-definite and . I would like to know when this problem has a solution and in this case what the minimizer $x^*$ is.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program), I read that in my case the problem is convex and "can be readily solved using interior point methods, as done with semidefinite programming". The only problem is that my optimization courses go back a long way and I don't know how to write my problem in the form of a semidefinite program. Maybe there is a much more effective method, I don't know.

Any help would be most welcome. Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/285881/91764). Note that I am not claiming it is a good idea to reduce to SDP.

Comment: For the case you portrait here, with positive definite (PD) A and B and a non-negative c, your problem always has an optimal solution which is x=0. The objective is always strictly positive except for x=0 (due to A being PD), and x=0 is a feasible solution (as c is positive), so that settles it. Maybe you want to expand your assumptions so we can provide a more comprehensive answer?

Comment: Yes thank you Rodrigo. But even writing the problem in this form I don't understand how in your link the author identifies his final problem with an SDP problem.

Comment: Evrey convex QCQP is an SOCP (second order cone program), https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#convex-quadratic-sets, and that can be seen as an SDP by writing $xy\geq z^2$ as a 2x2 PSD matrix condition. However I am not sure how that could help you to go all the way to SDP since that is just syntactic (and probably a solver would undo it back to SOCP before solving). Just use a QCQP or SOCP solver.